# What are the advantages and disadvantages of an ordered list?

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to figure out what the advantages from the disadvantages of having an ordered list are, but I'm over here struggling to find the importance. I know that ordered lists can allow for binary search which is much more efficient over sequential search. Otherwise I'm at a loss though.

Comment: The "bad side" on sorted lists is, that it needs resources to sort them ( everytime a new value is added )

Comment: I only use an ordered data set when I actually need one.  If you want speed but don't care about order, a hashed based unordered container is probably better.

Comment: compared to what? What is the advantage of a chair? You can sit on it. If you need a ordered list then you use an ordered list, what is advantage or disadvante depends on your requirements

Comment: Obviously compared to unordered. Question is extremely basic and probably answered multiple times on the site.

Comment: @ZackHenusens I can't really follow you. I don't yet understand what the question really is and I don't remember to have seen similar question before. If OP doesn't clarify, how is it "obvious" ?!

Comment: Basic algorithms, better comparison is whether you should make a chair or sit on the ground. Both work, which is better is circumstantial.

Comment: It also depends what a list is for you. Is it a linked list, like `std::list`, or contiguos memory like `std::vector` (what C# calls `List`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordering your data has many costs and benefits.

You are right in that it does enable a binary search.  But there are many ways to structure data so that searching for an element is fast; in the C++ standard library, `std::set` maintains its elements in order, while `std::unordered_set` doesn't, and the second is usually faster than the first.  (It uses hashes to find elements, as opposed to a binary search over a semi-balanced binary tree).

Often I'll order data to calculate differences between them, or have a canonical representation.  If I have two collections of data and they are unordered, checking equality is annoying (there are O(n^2) pairs to check).  If the data is in a canonical order, I can do O(n) work; if I trust a hashing function to be sufficiently robust, I can even pre-hash each element, and each sub-collection of elements, and check equality in O(1) time.

I can even find differences in O(size of difference) time with carefully ordered data and a trustworthy hash.

Ordered data is often what humans want; an inbox ordered randomly is not very useful, while one that is ordered by when the mail arrived, or even some kind of importance, is much better UI.

Ordered data can make branch prediction easier, and other optimizations at the hardware, compiler or algorithm level easier.  Here is a [classic SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array) about that issue; processing a sorted array is faster than an unsorted array, and the asker is surprised.

The hard part about programming is understanding what the hell is going on.  Data having structure makes reasoning about it easier; there are fewer things to *think* about.  A list being *always ordered* means that code that uses it can assume it is always ordered, which can make that code easier to think about and simpler, and then code that uses **that code** is in turn simpler and easier to think about.

The price, of course, is that almost all editing operations on an ordered list end up being more expensive, both in terms of computer time and programmer time to think about the consequences.  With a `std::vector`, adding K elements takes O(K) time; meanwhile, a naively sorted-after-each-operation `std::vector` would require O(K * N lg N) time, which can be horribly slow.

Not doing something is extremely valuable.  And code that doesn't do anything is easy to understand what it does.  By eliminating the "ordered" requirement, you make **writing** data to that storage easier to think about and easier for the computer to do.

Comment: This makes things so much clearer. Thank you so much for this detailed follow up. It really made everything click a lot more.